# Vuetify 2 skeleton-loader with manipulating "loading" in Vuex store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify `v-skeleton-loader` component wrapping a `v-data-table` component.

The `data-table` component is using server-side pagination and sorting.

To accomplish the server-side pagination, documentation suggests to watch the `options` object of the `data-table` and make a new API call with the changed options.
In my store module I set `state.loading = true` before the API request starts and `state.loading = false` right after the response is committed to the state.
On the `data-table` component I read that state for the `:loading` prop.

On its own this works fine.

When I now wrap the `data-table` with `v-skeleton-loader` and put the prop `:loading="loading"` I get an infinite loop of API requests and rendering of the `skeleton-loader`.

My hunch is that after the request got resolved and `state.loading = false` is set, the `skeleton-loader` unmounts and `data-table` mounts, changing the options which are being watched and a new API request is fired which sets `state.loading = true` and the `skeleton-loader` is being mounted again while `data-table` is unmounted. Which continues infinetely.

If that is correct, how do I resolve that issue?

Minimal example:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-card>
      <v-skeleton-loader
        :loading="loading"
        transition="scale-transition"
        height="500"
        type="table"
      >
        <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="orders"
          :fixed-header="true"
          :server-items-length="totalItems"
          :options.sync="options"
        >
        </v-data-table>
      </v-skeleton-loader>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
...
export default {
data() {
  return {
    options: {},
    ...
  }
},
  watch: {
    options: {
      handler() {
        this.getDataFromApi();
      },
      deep: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getDataFromApi() {
      // build query from options
      this.$store.dispatch("orders/getOrdersCustom", query);
    },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters("orders", ["orders"]),
    ...mapGetters("orders", ["loading"]),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("orders/getOrders");
  }
}
</script>
```

And the store module:

```js
const namespaced = true;

const state = {
  orders: [],
  loading: false,
};

const getters = {
  loading: (state) => state.loading,
  orders: (state) => state.orders.items,
};
const actions = {
  getOrdersCustom({ commit }, query) {
    commit("GET_ORDERS_REQUEST");

    return orderService.getOrdersCustom(query).then(
      (data) => commit("GET_ORDERS_SUCCESS", data),
      (error) => commit("GET_ORDERS_FAILURE", error)
    );
  },
}
const mutations = {
  GET_ORDERS_REQUEST(state) {
    state.loading = true;
  },
  GET_ORDERS_SUCCESS(state, data) {
    Vue.set(state.orders, "items", data["hydra:member"]);
    state.data = data;
    state.loading = false;
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I would do in this situation is have a separate variable in the local component state to track the initial loading state, and display the skeleton loader based on that.

Once the initial data set is loaded, I would use the data table component's built-in loading indicator for paginating/sorting the data.. it makes less sense to revert to the skeleton view, as you already have something rendered for the user to look at.

Comment: That is a good workaround and a better and more sensible solution for the problem I was trying to solve. This works well.